How to deploy ExternalSecret using Flux + Helm?
I have

Kubernetes (EKS) version 1.30
Flux v2
external-secrets latest version installed using the Flux guide

I don't understand how to integrate external-secret with ExternalSecret built using Helm.
ExternalSecret:
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: some-credentials
spec:
  refreshInterval: 1h
  secretStoreRef:
    name: aws-secretstore
    kind: SecretStore
  data:
  - secretKey: some-access-key
    remoteRef:
      key: {{ .Values.secrets.secretName }}
      property: some-access-key

I have the following CRs:
---
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: external-secrets-crs
  namespace: infra
spec:
  dependsOn:
    - name: external-secrets-crds
  interval: 1m
  path: ./charts/app-stack/templates/secrets
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: infra

The structure of my folder is:

charts

templates

secrets

secrets.yaml (all of the ExternalSecret objects)






apps

app.yaml



Flux is configured to track the apps folder
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: flux-system
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 10m0s
  path: ./apps
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: flux-system

app yaml
---
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: some-app-stack
  namespace: some-ns
spec:
  interval: 1m
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: ./charts/templates
      sourceRef:
        kind: GitRepository
        name: flux-system
        namespace: flux-system
  values:
    secrets:
      ...

The result is that no Secrets are created.
What should I do to integrate Flux Helm and external-secret to create dynamic secrets that depends on values?
